# How to use existing Docker image in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm a beginner in Docker and Kubernetes. I would like to know how I can create a Pod of Kubernetes with an already created image of Docker?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps

1. Tag the Docker image.
2. Push the image to registry (http://hub.docker.com/ or something else).
3. Run the image in a pod using the below command.

> kubectl run some-pod-name --image=image-name-in-registry --restart=Never

4. Check if the Pod is running or not.

> kubectl get pods

There are many other ways of creating a Pod, but this is the simplest way.

Also, there are the basics of K8S. Would recommend to go through the K8S documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home) and try different things.

If you don't have an access to K8S cluster, try the below. They can be done in the browser with zero-installation.

[Katakoda Kubernetes](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/kubernetes)

[Play with Kubernetes](https://training.play-with-kubernetes.com/kubernetes-workshop/)

[RedHat OpenShift](https://learn.openshift.com/)

Comment: Thanks for this help, but it's still not what I need!
In case I am trying to create a POD
using an existing Dockerfile file and a directory containing the application.
Example:
Dockerfile    app-test

Let's say I've already created a Docker image based on Dockerfile, and after that?
How can I create a POD with these files inside?

Comment: Those are the exact steps I mentioned in the Answer.